# Strange occurence of form within for loop PHP

Tags: php, forms, loops, include

I call a function in a for loop:

The function:

```
function shop_window($path, $id){

    //Add to shop window
    echo '<form action="/dashboard/'.$path.'/" name="'.$id.'" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="tcd.profile.add.to.shop.window"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="'.$id.'"/>
        </form>';

    echo '<a class="add_to_sw" href="#" onclick="document.'.$id.'.submit();" >Add to SW</a>';
}
```

The calling code:

```
//query rows = $rows
       if($rows){
              for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++){
           echo '<div style="float:right;text-align:right;">';
                  shop_window('cv', $db->result($result, $i, 'id'));
                  echo '<span style="font-size:10px;"> &bull; </span>';
                  echo '<a class="catalogue_tweet_this" href="#">Tweet this cv</a>';
           echo '</div>';
              }
        }
```

The problem with this code is that it only works for example, 2 out of the 4 iterations in the for loop. I.e on the 3rd and 4th iteration, once I click the link, the form does not seem to be active.

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @GrantThomas i wouldnt know where to start, its quite a big loop, this is just a part of it

Comment: Why use an anchor outside the form that triggers a JS submit? Why not simply use a `<button type="submit">` in the form?

Comment: You should add a log in your loop to check the value of `$db->result($result, $i, 'id')` at each iteration

Comment: to the above comment, i've already done that

Comment: turns out that I should have just used the submit button, i didnt know I could style it to what the link I was using was. Thanks, I think i've solved the problem